# Переживания влекут (или влечёт?) обнаружение

Tags: грамматика

Пожалуйста, скажите, как будет правильно: влекут или влечёт?

**Довольно сильные переживания влекут** (или **влечёт**) **за собой обнаружение несоответствия твоего окружения твоим мерилам.**

Answer (score 3):

Грамматически возможно и то, и другое, но с противоположным соотношением причины и следствия. В силу согласования глагола по числу с тем или иным существительным, в варианте "**влекут**" подлежащим (и причиной) оказываются "**переживания**" (из-за переживаний обнаруживается несоответствие), а в более правдоподобном варианте "**влечёт**" подлежащим становится "**обнаружение**" (по поводу обнаружения несоответствия возникают переживания).

Answer (score 1):

Довольно сильные переживания  **влечёт** за собой **обнаружение** несоответствия твоего окружения твоим мерилам.

Предикативная основа: **обнаружение влечёт**.  Влечет (что?) довольно сильные переживания. ***Переживания*** ― это дополнение (В.п.)

Здесь использован приём инверсии: дополнение вынесено в начало предложения, также сказуемое стоит перед подлежащим.

Цель инверсии ― выделить дополнение, придать ему особую значимость.